# How can I fix the purple screen of death when trying Ubuntu (14-04, 32-bits) from the liveCD?

Tags: boot, live-cd

**I burned a Live-CD of Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bits) and when I boot up the computer from the CD, it appears a purple frozen screen with a weird icon on the bottom. I think I've pressed every key on the keyboard to try to reach a menu of something but nothing seems to work. Most of the keys give me a "beep" sound when I press them.**
**I have a 2007 computer running Windows Vista (32-bits).**

Comment: System hang like this is a bug and you should report it on Launchpad. Most "purple screen" freezes are caused by GPU driver bugs. What GPU do you have?

Comment: GPU: SiS Mirage 3 Graphics.

Comment: Old SiS video chipsets are notoriously unsupported - see [Launchpad bug #301958](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/301958). There were closed source drivers for Ubuntu 12.04.1, you could try that, or just buy a decent supported 2nd hand ATI Radeon card.

Comment: Will I have the same problem if I try to install Mint?

Comment: Possibly. It does no harm to try. In my personal opinion, it isn't worth the time messing about with these old supported video chipsets - if this is a desktop I would just buy a supported card, a used Radeon card from ebay would be ~$5, if it were a laptop I would sell it and buy a Thinkpad T60 for $40. But that is just my personal opinion, others may differ. If you are a developer you could actually fix the Sis chip support, the discussions on xorg-devel suggest that the fix is probably simple, the driver used to work, someone has to spend the time to figure out when it broke.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Your computer may have UEFI. What year did you buy your PC?

The weird icon should be a person standing in a circle at a low resolution screen

What OS do you have on your PC that is bootable? Windows 7, Windows 8? If Windows 8, is Secure Boot on or off?

Comment: Secure Boot doesn't matter. Ever since Ubuntu 12.04.2 and 12.10, Ubuntu has had full support for Secure Boot. Also, whether or not Windows 8 is installed does NOT affect whether or not the computer has Secure Boot because Secure Boot is a setting that is implemented into the BIOS of every Windows 8 computer as a requirement, but is available in many computers, even ones that don't have Windows 8. Secure Boot is a requirement for Windows 8, but you don't need to have Windows 8 to have Secure Boot. I am sure that there are millions of Windows 7 computers that have Secure Boot enabled right now.

Comment: Secure Boot support was first implemented in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and was included with Windows 7. It's very likely that computers that don't come preinstalled with Windows or were made with Windows in mind at all have Secure Boot and have it enabled. Please know what you are talking about before you recommend solutions to others.

Comment: I´m running Windows Vista on a 2007 computer. I chose the 32 bits version of Ubuntu because my Windows Vista is a 32 bits version as well, and because my computer has just 1 GB of RAM.